# Day of year Javascript code won't run through sublime text editor

Tags: javascript, compilation

http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/dayweek.shtml

I am new to programming how do I run the Javascript code posted above through sublime text editor to chrome. What am I doing wrong here?

Also it says post in the body. So it that to say I have to add the usual: 
then`?

Comment: I recommend to read a JavaScript tutorial that explains how to add JavaScript to web pages. For example: http://quirksmode.org/js/placejs.html

Comment: Copy the code and save file as .html and open it in a browser

Comment: The tags confuse me: javascript + compilation. They dont mix together

Answer (score 0):

Normally JavaScript doesn't need compiling. When we say compile in JavaScript, we are generally talking about going from another language (Like TypeScript), or a light weight (Like CoffeeScript) language to JavaScript, or we are talking about minimizing the code (removing unnecessary white-space, comments, and line-breaks)

To do what you want to do, all you need is to open the file in a web browser. FireFox has both great tools for their browser, and a great website for JavaScript development.

If you are looking for more of a desktop environment for your JavaScript, over a browser environment, you may want to look into Node.js.

To be fair, CoffeeScript is JavaScript, just with all of the Shorthand being emphasized. So when you "compile" it, you are converting all of that short hand to more of a best practices style JavaScript.

Comment: And then there is Chrome which performs JIT compilation.

Comment: Well, yes Chrome does, and I suspect that the latest of both IE (11+) and FF do too, or will do soon. But that doesn't refer to the developer having to compile, which is what I suspect the original post was trying to resolve.